# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent in express-fileupload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
app.post('/profile', function(req, res) {
    // save file
    if (req.files) {
        let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;
        sampleFile.mv('/somewhere/on/your/server/filename.jpg', function(err) {
            if (err)
                return res.status(500).json(err);

        });
    }
    // do some other stuff
    // .............

    res.status(200).json(result);
});
```

I know the problem is caused by `return res.status(500).json(err)`. I can solve the problem by moving `res.status(200).json(result)` after `if (err)` block. Since upload file is optional, the user may posting other data without any uploading files. My question is how to send status 200 with a json result after processed other stuff if the solution is

```
if (err)
    return res.status(500).json(err);
res.status(200).json(result);
```

Comment: The problem here is the callback behavior. Everything inside the callback is executed **after** `other stuff` and  `res.status(200).json(result);` Which means your `.post()` sends status 200 and a possibly empty json no matter what, then optionally adds status 500 on top. The solution is to move everything you want to do if there isn't an error inside the callback.

Comment: try doing `return res.status(200).json(result);`

Comment: i tried `return res.status(200).json(result);` it does not work ;(

Comment: @RaxPat No it won't; vibhor is wrong. Have you tried what I suggested...?

Comment: @ChrisG I don't understand what you meant. how to move everything? I still need the req.files.sampleFile.name, req.files.sampleFile.mimetype (if file uploaded) and put it in to database along with other data.

Comment: @RaxPat You need to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4smof4on/ (also known as "callback hell", which is why people invented `Promise`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was pointed above the problem is you are sending the success reponse outside of the callback.

The solution is to do "other stuff" within the callback.

This should fix the issue -

```
app.post('/profile', function(req, res) {
    // save file
    if (req.files) {
        let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;
        sampleFile.mv('/somewhere/on/your/server/filename.jpg', function(err) {
            if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);

            doOtherStuff();
            res.status(200).json(result);
        });
    } else {
       doOtherStuff();
       res.status(200).json(result);
    }
});

// Write a do other stuff function
function doOtherStuff() {
  // do stuff
}
```

**EDIT** Adding answer with [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to avoid code repetition.

```
function moveFile(file, somePlace) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
   file.mv(somePlace, function(err) {
     if (err) return reject(err);

     resolve();
   });
  });
}

app.post('/profile', function(req, res) {
  // save file if present

  const fileMovePromise  = req.files ? 
    moveFile(req.files.sampleFile, '/somewhere/on/your/server/filename.jpg') 
    : 
    Promise.resolve('No file present');

  fileMovePromise
    .then(() => {
      // do other stuff
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: what if the user didn't upload file? uploading file is optional.

Comment: Wrap "do some other stuff in a function" and call it in both places. Updating answer to show how.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a form of middleware to check if the post is uploading files, the act on the file upload before continuing, have a look at middleware with express here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

With middleware you can do your check to see if the file needs uploading and then call next, otherwise just call next.

```
app.use('/profile', function (req, res, next) {
 if (req.files) {
   let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;
   sampleFile.mv('/somewhere/on/your/server/filename.jpg', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    } else {
      req.data = data
      next()
    }
 });
}
 res.status(200);
}, function (req, res) {
 res.status(500).json(req.data);
})
```

If you are using Node for express, the res param contains res.headersSent, which you can check if the headers have already been sent.

```
if(res.headersSent) {}
```

You can also find out a lot more here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_headerssent

Comment: I've pulled my downvote for now, but this doesn't really address the issue.

Comment: The issue is that you are just not knowing if you have a file upload or not, but using a middleware to handle this would really help, and give better structure. A middleware will not continue unless you call the Next() function call!, allowing you to have that option of uploading or not!

Comment: `.mv` callback function didn't provides `data` parameter

Comment: It was just an example, showing that this is the section you would handle your file and do "other stuff".